# Differing jquery offset().top values between refresh and load in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, offset

I am using the following function to manually perform scroll to anchor links on my page:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
if (hash != ''){
      var anchor = $('#' + hash + '_hash').offset().top - 50;
      $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: anchor}, 1000)
};
```

The code is working as it should except I get differing values for `offset().top` in chrome specifically and always by 40px between refresh and actual page load. On refresh I get the correct value and on page load by typing the url or opening in a new tab I get the same value minus 40px.

I have moved this function to `$(window).load(function () {...});` as I thought it might be some cached elements loading changing the values but the problem persists.

Anyone got any idea why this might be happening? I tried searching for similar questions/answers but am yet to find anything so I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate thread.

Comment: same thing happening to me, really odd can not find a solution